# Check float Against array but skips values

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have this script that does `reflectionProbe.RenderProbe()` on fixed value from time, problem is that sometimes it skips a value from the array. What am I doing wrong?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/9NwVq7X.png]

```
public float secondsInFullDay = 120f;
private float[] floatDay = new float[40] {
    0, 250, 500, 750, 1000, 1250, 1500, 1750, 2000,
    2250, 2500, 2750, 3000, 3250, 3500, 3750, 4000, 
    4250, 4500, 4750, 5000, 5250, 5500, 5750, 6000,
    6250, 6500, 6750, 7000, 7250, 7500, 7750, 8000,
    8250, 8500, 8750, 9000, 9250, 9500, 9750};

[Range(0,1)]
public float currentTimeOfDay = 0f;

public float TimeOfDay = 0f;
public float timeMultiplier = 1f;

void Update() {
    currentTimeOfDay += (Time.deltaTime / secondsInFullDay) * timeMultiplier;

    if (currentTimeOfDay >= 1) {
        currentTimeOfDay = 0;
    }

    TimeOfDay = currentTimeOfDay * 10000 / timeMultiplier;
    TimeOfDay = Mathf.Round(TimeOfDay);


    foreach (float x in floatDay){
    float y = x / timeMultiplier;
        if (TimeOfDay == y){
            reflectionProbe.RenderProbe();
            Debug.Log ("refresh probe " + y);
        }       
    }
}
```

Comment: When you said **sometimes** it skips, could it be due to the rounding here `TimeOfDay = Mathf.Round(TimeOfDay);`? What interval are you indenting?, and time of the day is `0f`, multiplier is `1f`. Why are they different?

Comment: well this is how it should be - public float TimeOfDay; and yes it might be due to TimeOfDay = Mathf.Round(TimeOfDay); but mostlly because of the statement to check if the TimeOfDay  = floatDay[]

Comment: You could standardize all floats variables', floating points.

Comment: I wonder if you should be using [Mathf.Epsilon](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.Epsilon.html)?

Answer (score 1):

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(TimeOfDay, y))
{
    //Do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

most likely you have a problem with the floating point.

debug log all your float values (x, y, TimeOfDay)

i suspect that y is the problematic one

most likely you will have to use:

```
if (TimeOfDay > y - 1e-7f && TimeOfDay < y + 1e-7f)
```

instead of

```
if (TimeOfDay == y)
```

Comment: It's the same. But If I make  TimeOfDay = currentTimeOfDay * 1000 / timeMultiplier; and float y = x / timeMultiplier / 10; it debugs 3-5 in console

Comment: try this: 'if (TimeOfDay > y - 1f && TimeOfDay < y + 1f)'

Comment: It worked with 1e-5f and 10000 in TimeOfDay, I know it's a really weird script :)) L.E seems that it's still skipping some values lol

Comment: it does not have to be that complicated. i also answered your other question, the problem is the same ;)